# mdadm RAID5 mismatch, which file(s) on ext4 filesystem are affected?

Tags: ext4, mdadm, software-raid, raid5

After a scrub of my 4-disk RAID5 mdadm array I got these log entries:

```
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340608-204340616
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340616-204340624
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340624-204340632
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340632-204340640
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340640-204340648
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340648-204340656
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340656-204340664
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340664-204340672
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340672-204340680
Dec 03 07:20:53 srv10 kernel: md1: mismatch sector in range 204340680-204340688
```

How can I find the file(s) affected on the ext4 filesystem?
I would like to inform file-owner of a possible corruption.

Tried to use the method described in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266432/md-raid5-translate-md-internal-sector-numbers-to-offsets) but didn't manage to "translate" it to my setup. Use 4K-sector disks and ext4.

Superblock on the disks (same on all 4):

```
 mdadm -E /dev/sdh3
/dev/sdh3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 05346821:52973e66:6ebd7f2d:ef64dcca
           Name : localhost:R5_01
  Creation Time : Wed Dec 16 17:53:50 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1827202440 sectors (871.28 GiB 935.53 GB)
     Array Size : 2740803648 KiB (2.55 TiB 2.81 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 1827202432 sectors (871.28 GiB 935.53 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0d31c56e:a07be732:8258d07a:b05813bf

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Dec  3 12:49:22 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : ac57370b - correct
         Events : 4651

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Partitions of the 4 disks (RAID5 on part. 3)

```
Total size:                   931.51GB
Logical- / physical sector:   4096 / 4096
Total sectors:                244190646
First usable sector:          6
Last usable sector:           244190640

Partitions on  /dev/sdc
ID  PartNo  DevName    Label   Start-sector  End-sector    Sectors       Size  Type        
--  ------  ---------  ------  ------------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ----------
1   1       /dev/sdc1  P1-EFI          2048       28671      26624  104.0 MiB  EFI System
2   2       /dev/sdc2  P5-R10         28672    15757311   15728640   60.0 GiB  Linux RAID
3   3       /dev/sdc3  P9-R5       15757312   244190640  228433329  871.4 GiB  Linux RAID
```

EXT4 properties:

```
#dumpe2fs -h /dev/md1
Filesystem volume name:   R5_01
Last mounted on:          /mnt/R5_DATA
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem state:         clean
Inode count:              42825728
Block count:              685200912
Free blocks:              207789491
Free inodes:              42129576
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         2048
Inode blocks per group:   128
RAID stride:              16
RAID stripe width:        48
Flex block group size:    16
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
```

I also got some EXT4 error that I fixed with `e2fsck`:

```
Dec 02 19:35:21 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs (md1): error count since last fsck: 7004
Dec 02 19:35:21 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs (md1): initial error at time 1663363366: ext4_xattr_block_get:534: inode 4789231
Dec 02 19:35:21 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs (md1): last error at time 1670003362: ext4_xattr_block_list:707: inode 4789224
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error: 26 callbacks suppressed
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_get:534: inode #4789231: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627790
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_list:707: inode #4789231: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627790
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_get:534: inode #4789228: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627787
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_list:707: inode #4789228: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627787
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_get:534: inode #4789231: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627790
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_list:707: inode #4789231: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627790
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_get:534: inode #4789228: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627787
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_list:707: inode #4789228: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627787
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_get:534: inode #4789221: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627780
Dec 02 20:35:11 srv10 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_xattr_block_list:707: inode #4789221: comm smbd: corrupted xattr block 76627780
```

When/if I manage to pinpoint the file(s) I assume I should do a `echo repair > /sys/block/md1/md/sync_action` and then do a new ext4 check.

It's not very likely these errors is coursed by any bad-block.....that should `md` be able to fix automatically, right?

SMART looks good for all 4 drives.

And then I need to take a look at ZFS!